# Orchard Tenant enabling themes in console

Tags: orchardcms, multi-tenant

Is there possibility to enable specific themes for tenants on Orchard console?

After created tenant all themes are available to enable/disable. But how can I add only selected themes to tenant in Orchard Console as I can do in Orchard Admin Site for specific tenant ?

Answer (score 0):

All tenants see all themes as well as all modules available in this Orchard instance by design. To activate a theme from command line for a single tenant only, use command `theme activate "<theme name>" /t:<tenant name>`.

`/t` switch denotes a tenant for which a given command is to be executed. It's applicable to all commands.

Comment: That means that I can not execute command to append specific themes to tenant? The only possible way is do it manual on main Orchard Dashboard? (or edit Settings.txt?)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution by creating new module and implementing new console command.

There I can inject orchard tenant service and update specified with my own themes list.
Useful information here: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Using-the-command-line-interface#AddingCommands